# Portfolio variance $<=$ weighted average of individual variances

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, variance, mean-variance, markowitz

In portfolio theory, I often (with some justifications but the message is the same) come across the following statement:

*"The most important quality of portfolio variance is that its value is a weighted combination of the individual variances of each of the assets adjusted by their covariances. **This means that the overall portfolio variance is lower than a simple weighted average of the individual variances of the stocks in the portfolio.**"*

Link of quote: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/portfolio-variance.asp

So, the text in bold is my problem. ***"The overall portfolio variance is lower than a simple weighted average of the individual variances of the stocks in the portfolio."***

Can anyone prove this or refer to an link where it is proven?

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase is "adjusted by their covariances". The formula for the variance of a portfolio of two assets is

$\sigma _{p}^{2}=w_{A}^{2}\sigma _{A}^{2}+w_{B}^{2}\sigma _{B}^{2}+2w_{A}w_{B}\sigma _{A}\sigma _{B}\rho _{AB}$

, which, since $\rho _{AB} <= 1$, is always less than

$ w_{A}^{2}\sigma _{A}^{2}+w_{B}^{2}\sigma _{B}^{2}+2w_{A}w_{B}\sigma _{A}\sigma _{B} $

$=  (w_{A}\sigma _{A}+w_{B}\sigma _{B})^{2}$

That said, the wording in the article is inaccurate; it's more accurate to say that the *standard deviation* of a portfolio is lower (or at worst, equal to) a weighted average of the *standard deviations of returns* of the constituents.